# Windows 10 Temp folder taking up a lot of space

Tags: disk-space

I need some help. The %systemdrive%\Windows\Temp folder grows really quickly and can reach 25GB in a few days. Most of the files in it are event log files. I tried searching this up, but I didn't find anything useful. This is getting annoying as i only have 30GB free. (I use an SSD as my system drive), there is two users on this computer and the logs only appear on one account (it doesn't happen on the other account). The Microsoft store on the 'broken' account crashes instantly so I think it has something to do with that.

The temp folder looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QDlr.png) and [here's](https://mega.nz/#!bV9CDazR!-prl83RVI77b5fxazjoqU_r-F28iuNgzhTfH265zflk) one of the files

Comment: Those aren't event logs.. not in the traditional sense.  Event logs aren't just text files and they reside in "%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\ ", not it your system temp folder.  You need to figure out what is dumping all of that crap into your system temp folder by looking at the files and doing some sleuthing.  Because a file ends in .log doesn't make it an event log.

Comment: If you don't use the windows store (I don't) you can disable the service through the group policy editor.  https://whatsabyte.com/windows/fix-wsappx-high-cpu-usage-problem/

Comment: To disable Windows Store without GPEDIT, you have to use the Windows Registry.  On the page I suggested.. there is a section for windows 8.1.. it is probably the same and certainly won't hurt you.  I also saw pages telling me how to do it in windows 10 which I am currently too lazy to google again. ;)  (hint hint)

Comment: the regedit method didnt work but i uninstalled microsoft store using `Get-AppxPackage *windowsstore* | Remove-AppxPackage`, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 0):

In event viewer (eventvwr.msc), you can set log size limits, and how to handle full logs.  Right click on one of the logs, choose properties and set the configuration as you wish it to be.

The default config on Win 10 home is 20 Mb, overwrite as needed.  This does not use the %systemdrive%\Windows\Temp folder, so something is modified on your system.

Comment: I doubt that something on his machine is modified.. his files simply aren't system event logs and this doesn't help him solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are these AppXDeploymentServer event logs?

If so, follow the instructions given at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4458149/windows-10-low-disk-space-error-due-to-a-full-temp-folder

Comment: i think they were appx files but im not sure, i deleted them today again. i will try your solution and if it works i will make sure to mark your post as the solution!

Comment: Do the files automatically regenerate after deleting them? Also, are they AppX event logs, or something else like .evtx?

If either, it could be a rehash of older issues. One method would be:

Click your Start Button, type regedit and hit Enter to open the Registry Editor // Click View and make sure 'Address Bar' is turned on  // Paste this into the Address Bar at the top and hit Enter // HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AppXSvc  // In the right hand pane, double click Start // Set its value to 4 // Clock OK , close the Registry Editor and restart your PC //

Comment: That's not a perfect fix though, especially if you actually use any Windows Store apps. What would take longer, but might be more effective, is to uninstall all Windows Store apps through PowerShell, then only reinstall the ones you need. More on that at https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/uninstall-restore-windows-10-builtin-apps